# Codename One - Reliable way to get all logs generated by Log.p() and Log.e() in a String

Tags: codenameone

In a development stage of my app, for me it's convenient to get all the logs generated by `Log.p()` and `Log.e()` in a String (for example to show them in a Dialog or to send them by email with a method different from your Log.sendLog()).

That's why I created the following method. My questions is if it's reliable and if I haven't replicated something that already exists:

```
/**
 * Get all logs of the app generated with Log.p() or Log.e()
 * @return All logs of the app generated with Log.p() or Log.e()
 */
public static String getAllLogs() {
    String logs = "";
    try {
        logs = Util.readToString(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("CN1Log__$"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logs = "";
    }
    return logs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with this approach is the various ways in which OS's handle open files so I would avoid using that as it might trigger a crash by inspection e.g. you open a file to read while you are writing into it.

On iOS/Android this should work fine as they are unix based but on Windows it might be challenging. Large logs in a memory constrained device might also lead to a crash here.